# Cambiar color de los outliers - DBSCAN y Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster, agrupación

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual, a partir de una base de datos de mensajes AIS, busco agrupaciones de barcos para detección de rutas marítimas, fondeaderos, zonas de pesca...

Con una dataframe así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la hora de representar los clústeres, una vez aplicado el algoritmo (DBSCAN en este caso), utilizo cartopy con matplotlib para plotearlos sobre un mapa, con el siguiente código:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution="10m")
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent([min(X["lon"]-1), max(X["lon"]+1), 34, max(X["lat"]+1)], ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.scatter(X["lon"], X["lat"],
        c=db.labels_,
        s=10,
        alpha=1,
        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

El resultado es el de la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que me gustaría saber hacer dos cosas aquí:

1. Plotear únicamente los outliers (ruido)
2. Cambiar el color de los outliers a otro que destaque más, como el rojo (por defecto es el color morado oscuro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, creo que ya he encontrado como hacerlo. Para quien le interese, el código que he usado es:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution="10m")
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent([min(X["lon"]-1), max(X["lon"]+1), 34, max(X["lat"]+1)], 
ccrs.PlateCarree())

for i in range(0,len(labels)):
    if labels[i] == -1:
        plt.scatter(X.lon[i], X.lat[i],
            c= "r",
            s=10,
            alpha=1,
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que sigo sin saber es como cambiar únicamente el color de los outliers en el primer caso, ploteando todos los puntos.